# Need to know how to parse words by space in c. Also need to know if I am allocating memory correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, tokenize, dynamic-arrays

I am writing a program in c that reads in text from a text file then randomly selects  words from the file and if the words are greater than or equal to six it appends the words together, removes the spaces, and finally prints the new word. (I am using the redirect on linux "<" to read in the file)

> ```
> Example input: "cheese and crackers"
>
> New word should be: cheesecrackers
> ```

Here is the code:

```
int main (void)
{
    int ch;
    char *ptrChFromFile;
    int strSize = 1;
    int i;
    int numberOfWords = 1;

    ptrChFromFile = malloc (sizeof (char));

    if (ptrChFromFile == NULL) {
        puts ("COULDN'T ALLOICATE MEMORY");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((ch = getchar ()) != EOF) {
        ptrChFromFile =
            realloc (ptrChFromFile, (strSize + 1) * sizeof (char));

        if (ptrChFromFile == NULL) {
            puts ("failed to allocate memory");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (ch == ' ') {
            numberOfWords++;
        }

        ptrChFromFile[strSize] = ch;
        strSize++;
    }

    ptrChFromFile[strSize] = 0;

    char **ptrWords = malloc (sizeof (char *) * strSize);


    for (i = 0; i < strSize; i++) {
        if (ptrChFromFile[i] != ' ') {
            ptrWords[i] = &ptrChFromFile[i];
        }
        else {
            ptrWords[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    free (ptrChFromFile);
    free (ptrWords);
    return 0;
}
```

The things that I am struggling with are:

1) Am I allocating the correct memory size for the pointers?

2) How can I parse each word by space without using any special methods from the string.h library (like strtok). Then how do I store those words in the pointer *ptrWords?

so ptrWords should look like this:

---

> cheese | and | crackers
>
> ```
>  0        1      2
> ```

---

Then I want to loop through ptrWords and check if the length of each word in the pointer is greater than or equal to six. If they are store them in the pointer ptrOutputWord.

so then ptrOutputWord should look like this:

---

> cheese | crackers
>
> ```
>  0        1
> ```

---

Finally, I want to print the values in ptrOutputWord as one word without spaces.

I tried to explain what I want to do exactly. Thank you to anyone that can help in advance.

EDIT: I changed the code to reflect only the piece that should read in the characters, and reallocate the size of the pointer by one each time a new character is read in, but the right amount of memory isn't being allocated.

Comment: 1) No. You're not allocating the memory correctly. You're allocating a single `char` of memroy. `sizeof(char)` should make that pretty clear. 2) Sounds like that's what your assignment is asking you to figure out. Your instructor would probably not be happy if we did it for you instead.

Comment: It's not clear that you initialize `strSize`, so incrementing it is dubious.  You are leaking memory like fury because you always use `malloc()` and never `realloc()`.  Adding one character at a time is slow; double the amount of memory allocated, and keep tabs on it.  The code at `ptrChFromFile = &ch; 
     strSize ++;
     ptrChFromFile = (char*)malloc(strSize * sizeof(char)+1);` is horribly broken for a variety of reasons.

Comment: What are the numbers in the second line of your output supposed to mean? After you merge your words there is no second word but only one longer word. Otherwise your example at the top of your question is not correct.

Comment: You only call `rand` once. To concatenate some words you should add some mechanism to select more than one word and to somehow determine the number how many random words to pick

Comment: General hints: First things first! Split your problem: 1. read from file, 2. separate words, 3. store words, 4. select random word, 5. check length and add to new word. 6. repeat 4&5 until some limit reached 7. print output. Only if one of these steps works for you, continue to implement the next step.

Comment: @Gerhardh I revised the code to split things up as you suggested. Any further help you could offer would be great. Please see edit

Comment: @Gerhardh I am now trying to add the words into ptrWords but I don't think think I am doing it correctly. I think I allocated memory correctly for ptrWords, I don't think I am storing them correctly. my logic is as long as you don't find a space add the word to new pointer, but when a space is found put a terminating character in its place. i have updated the code am I storing the words correctly?

Comment: No. First so the excercise on paper. Then step through the code in a debugger. Compare the values with expectations. Anderen please don't alter the question. It destroys context for comments and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
```

Why this header?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char ch, *ptrChFromFile; 
  int strSize;
```

This variable needs to have a useful start value.

```
  ptrWordsFromFile = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

No need to cast.

```
  if(ptrChFromFile == NULL)
  {
     puts("COULDN'T ALLOICATE MEMORY");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
```

`getchar` returns and `int`, not a `char`.

```
  {
    ptrChFromFile  = (char*)realloc(ptrChFromFile, strSize * sizeof(char)+1);
```

We need one more character than before and extra space for the `0`. 
You should add the +2 (not +1) to the number of elements: `(strSize+2) * sizeof(<any type>)`

Normally you should not directly assign the result of `realloc` to the same pointer. In case it fails, you lose your old pointer value. Again: No cast needed.

```
    if(ptrChFromFile == NULL)
      {puts("failed to alloicate memory");}
```

If it fails, you cannot continue! Exit from the program just as above

```
    *ptrChFromFile = ch;
```

You put the character to the start of the enlarged buffer. You should add at the end.

```
    strSize++;
  }
```

Now you have a bunch of characters in memory but no termination for the string.

```
  free(ptrChFromFile);
  return 0;
}
```

After fixing it it looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int ch;
  char *ptrChFromFile; 
  int strSize = 0;

  ptrWordsFromFile = malloc(sizeof(char));

  if (ptrChFromFile == NULL)
  {
     puts("COULDN'T ALLOICATE MEMORY");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
    ptrChFromFile = realloc(ptrChFromFile, (strSize+2) * sizeof(char));

    if (ptrChFromFile == NULL)
    {
      puts("failed to allocate memory");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ptrChFromFile[strSize] = ch;
    strSize++;
  }
  ptrChFromFile[strSize] = 0;

  // Now add detection and storing of separate words
  // (You might omit storing words that are too short)
  // Select random words and add together.

  free(ptrChFromFile);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me into sections. I didn't even think to add the characters in from the back. A very good explanation. Thank you. Now I have to have another pointer that stores the separate words. Is it possible in c to store the words in a pointer such that the first word (not character) would be at index zero? So when I am selecting a random word from the pointer I can say this: ptrOutputWord = ptrWords[randomIndex] where if the randomIndex is 0 it stores the first word in ptrWords to ptrOutputWord.

Comment: For your words you need to use a double pointer: `char **words = malloc(sizeof(char*)*num_words);` Then `words[i]` can hold the address of the ith word, starting at 0. You don't need to allocate new memory for your words. You can use the initial memory and just store pointers into that area. Don't forget to terminate each word. I suggest to go ahead with that approach and open another question if you struggle.