# dynamic allocate double pointer in c

Tags: c, tokenize, dynamic-memory-allocation, double-pointer

This question is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035450/need-to-know-how-to-parse-words-by-space-in-c-also-need-to-know-if-i-am-allocat?noredirect=1#comment96898635_55035450).

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    char *ptrChFromFile;
    char **ptrWords;
    int strSize = 1;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int numberOfWords = 1;

    ptrChFromFile = malloc(sizeof(char));

    if (ptrChFromFile == NULL)
    {
        puts("COULDN'T ALLOICATE MEMORY");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        ptrChFromFile = realloc(ptrChFromFile, (strSize+1) * sizeof(char));

        if (ptrChFromFile == NULL)
        {
            puts("failed to allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            numberOfWords++;
        }

        ptrChFromFile[strSize] = ch;
        strSize++;
    }

    ptrChFromFile[strSize] = 0;

    ptrWords = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numberOfWords); //creates number of slots in ptr

    if (ptrWords == NULL)
    {
        puts("failed to allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) // allocates number of bytes in each slot.
    {
        ptrWords[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*)* strSize);
        if (ptrWords[i] == NULL)
        {
            puts("failed to allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < strSize; i++)
    {
        if (ptrChFromFile[i] != ' ')
        {
            ptrWords[j] = &ptrChFromFile[i];
        }
        else
        {
            ptrWords[j] = 0;
            j++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) // free's each slot in ptrWords
    {
        free(ptrWords[i]);
    }

    free(ptrChFromFile);
    free(ptrWords);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to dynamically allocate my double char pointer ptrWords. Allow me to explain my thought process:

```
ptrWords = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numberOfWords); //creates number of slots in ptr
```

This creates the number of slots (indices) in ptrWords. so if I have 3 words ptrWords should look like this:

ptrWords[index 0]

ptrWords[index 1]

ptrWords[index 2]

```
for (i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) // allocates number of bytes in each slot.
{
    ptrWords[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*)* strSize);
    if (ptrWords[i] == NULL)
    {
        puts("failed to allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

This for loop allocates memory to each slot in ptrWords equal to the total number of characters in the input file. So if the input file has 26 total characters for example then each slot in ptrWords will have 26 bytes allocated to it.

ptrWords[index 0] has 26 bytes of memory

ptrWords[index 1] has 26 bytes of memory

ptrWords[index 2] has 26 bytes of memory

I think my memory allocation of ptrWords is correct, but I am not sure.

```
for (i = 0; i < strSize; i++)
{
    if (ptrChFromFile[i] != ' ')
    {
        ptrWords[j] = &ptrChFromFile[i];
    }
    else
    {
        ptrWords[j] = 0;
        j++;
    }
}
```

This for loop is supposed to take the characters from ptrChFromFile and store them in ptrWords as separate words. My logic with loop is as follows:

1) As long as ch does not equal a space take that character and store it at the first position (index 0) of ptrWords.

2) if ch does equal a space then place a terminating character ('\0') in its place then increment j by 1 to move to the next index in ptrWords to store the next word.

I have used a debugger to step through the code, but I still can't figure out whats wrong, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

---

My implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    char *ptrChFromFile;
    char **ptrWords;
    int strSize = 1;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int numberOfWords = 1;

    ptrChFromFile = malloc(sizeof(char));

    if (ptrChFromFile == NULL)
    {
        puts("COULDN'T ALLOCATE MEMORY");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        ptrChFromFile = realloc(ptrChFromFile, (strSize+1) * sizeof(char));

        if (ptrChFromFile == NULL)
        {
            puts("failed to allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            numberOfWords++;
        }

        ptrChFromFile[strSize] = ch;
        strSize++;
    }

    ptrChFromFile[strSize] = 0;

    ptrWords = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numberOfWords); //creates number of slots in ptrWords

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) // allocates number of bytes in each slot.
    {
        ptrWords[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*)* strSize);
        if (ptrWords[i] == NULL)
        {
            puts("failed to allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if (ptrWords == NULL)
    {
        puts("failed to allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < strSize; i++)
    {
        if (ptrChFromFile[i] != ' ')
        {
            ptrWords[j][k++] = ptrChFromFile[i];
        }
        else
        {
            ptrWords[j][k] = 0;
            ptrWords[j] = realloc(ptrWords[j], k+1);
            j++;
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", ptrWords[0]);

    free(ptrChFromFile);
    free(ptrWords);

    return 0;
}
```

sample input: "hey there"

output: hey there

¿hey

---

Current version of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int getStrLength(char *word)
{
    int lengthOfWord = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; word[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        lengthOfWord++;
    }
    return lengthOfWord;
}

int compareWords(char *firstWord, char *secondWord)
{
    while (*firstWord && *firstWord == *secondWord)
    {
        firstWord++;
        secondWord++;
    }
    return *firstWord - *secondWord;
}

int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    char *ptrChFromFile;
    char **ptrWords;
    char **ptrCrunchWord;
    int strSize = 0;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int numberOfWords = 0;
    int defaultWordLength = 6;

    srand(time(0)); // Use current time as seed for random generator

    ptrChFromFile = malloc(sizeof(char));

    if (ptrChFromFile == NULL)
    {
        puts("COULDN'T ALLOCATE MEMORY");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') // this reads in chars from file to ch variable
    {
        ptrChFromFile = realloc(ptrChFromFile, (strSize+1) * sizeof(char));

        if (ptrChFromFile == NULL)
        {
            puts("failed to allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            numberOfWords++;
        }

        ptrChFromFile[strSize] = ch;
        strSize++;
    }

    numberOfWords++;
    ptrChFromFile[strSize] = 0;

    ptrWords = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numberOfWords); //creates number of slots in ptrWords

    if (ptrWords == NULL)
    {
        puts("failed to allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) // allocates number of bytes in each slot.
    {
        ptrWords[i] = malloc(strSize);
        if (ptrWords[i] == NULL)
        {
            puts("failed to allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < strSize; i++) // This inserts words in ptrWords separated by spaces.
    {
        if (ptrChFromFile[i] != ' ')
        {
            ptrWords[j][k++] = ptrChFromFile[i];
        }
        else
        {
            ptrWords[j][k] = 0;
            ptrWords[j] = realloc(ptrWords[j], k+1);
            j++;
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    // terminate and resize last word
    ptrWords[j][k] = 0;
    ptrWords[j] = realloc(ptrWords[j], k+1);
    j = 0;
    k = 0;

    // crunchWord code starts here:
      ptrCrunchWord = malloc(sizeof(char*));
      ptrCrunchWord[0] = malloc(strSize);

      if (ptrCrunchWord == NULL || ptrCrunchWord[0] == NULL)
       {
           puts("failed to allocate memory");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }


    for (i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++)
    {
        int randomIndex = rand() % numberOfWords;

    if (compareWords(ptrCrunchWord[i], ptrWords[randomIndex]) != 0) 
    {
        if (getStrLength(ptrWords[randomIndex]) >= defaultWordLength) 
        {
            ptrCrunchWord[i] = ptrWords[randomIndex]; // main problem here
        }
    }
}

    printf("The crunch word is: %s", ptrCrunchWord[0]);


    for (i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) // Free's allocated memory from all pointers
    {
        free(ptrWords[i]);
    }

    free(ptrChFromFile);
    free(ptrWords);
    free(ptrCrunchWord[0]);
    free(ptrCrunchWord);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the most current code. The last thing I need to do is store all words that are greater than or equal to six in ptrCrunchWord. My main issue is allocating space in ptrCrunchWord[0] for the final crunch word and storing the words in index 0. I am only allocating space for the element because there will be only one word stored in ptrCrunchWord. I have written two methods one checks the length of each word and the other method compares two words to see if they are the same. Finally, I need to print the crunch word with no spaces.

Thank you

Comment: Which problem are you facing?

Comment: You have a big memory leak. First you're allocating memory for each `ptrWords` element, but the next loop replaces those pointers with pointers into `ptrChFromFile`. Did you mean to copy the strings from one array to the other, instead of assigning pointers?

Comment: And after you assign all those pointers, it's no longer valid to `free(ptrWords[i])`, since those pointers were not returned by `malloc/realloc`.

Comment: @alk sorry if that wasn't clear when I try to print the first element in ptrWords using printf("%s", ptrWords[0]); I get (null) so the words aren't being stored correctly in the pointer.

Comment: @Barmar I want to copy the characters from ptrChWordsFromFile to ptrWords as separate words separated by spaces. For example "hey there" in ptrWords would be: hey (index 0) | there (index 1). I have to use pointers because I'm reading in input from a text file.

Comment: Why do you want to allocate new memory for the words instead of using the first buffer that already holds everything? Your first approach was not bad but you fortog to terminate the words in the buffer. How many words do you want to add together afterwards? You use `numberOfWords` which is total number of words in the file. This is probably not correct as it also includes words that are too short. BTW: Why do you store words that are not long enough in your words array at all?

Comment: You might also add handling for multiple spaces in a row...

Comment: I need help writing a function that will delete repeating words

Comment: My answer below avoids duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop is wrong:

```
for (i = 0; i < strSize; i++)
{
    if (ptrChFromFile[i] != ' ')
    {
        ptrWords[j] = &ptrChFromFile[i];
    }
    else
    {
        ptrWords[j] = 0;
        j++;
    }
}
```

You shouldn't be reassigning `ptrWords[j]`, you should copy into the memory you allocated in the previous loop. You need another variable `k` to hold the index you're assigning in the destination array.

```
int k = 0;
for (i = 0; i < strSize; i++)
{
    if (ptrChFromFile[i] != ' ')
    {
        ptrWords[j][k++] = ptrChFromFile[i];
    }
    else
    {
        ptrWords[j][k] = 0;
        j++;
        k = 0;
    }
}
```

You also went way overboard in the amount of memory you assigned for `ptrWords`. Each word has as many characters allocated as the entire size of the file. When you reach the end of each word, after assigning `ptrWords[j][k] = 0` you can shrink that allocation to the size of the word with:

```
ptrWords[j] = realloc(ptrWords[j], k+1);
```

Another problem is that you initialized `strSize = 1;`. That's causing you to put the first character of the input into `ptrChFromFile[1]` instead of `ptrChFromFile[0]`, so the first word doesn't get copied correctly. It should be initialized as `int strSize = 0`. But to adjust for this change, you need to increase all the `ptrChFromFile` allocations by 1 character (or do another `realloc` at the end to add space for the trailing null).

When you're allocating the memory for `ptrWords[i]`, you shouldn't multiply by `sizeof(char *)`. `ptrWords` is an array of pointers, `ptrWords[i[` is an array of `char`.

After you finish the loop that reads the initial input into `ptrChFromFile`, you need to increment `numberOfWords`. Otherwise you won't count the last word before the newline.

You shouldn't have removed the loop at the end that frees all the `ptrWords[i]`. Anything you allocate with `malloc` needs to be freed.

Here's the working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    char *ptrChFromFile;
    char **ptrWords;
    int strSize = 0;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int numberOfWords = 1;

    ptrChFromFile = malloc(2);

    if (ptrChFromFile == NULL)
    {
        puts("COULDN'T ALLOCATE MEMORY");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        ptrChFromFile = realloc(ptrChFromFile, (strSize+2));

        if (ptrChFromFile == NULL)
        {
            puts("failed to allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (ch == ' ')
        {
            numberOfWords++;
        }

        ptrChFromFile[strSize] = ch;
        strSize++;
    }
    numberOfWords++; // increment for last word

    ptrChFromFile[strSize] = 0;

    ptrWords = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numberOfWords); //creates number of slots in ptrWords

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++) // allocates number of bytes in each slot.
    {
        ptrWords[i] = malloc(strSize);
        if (ptrWords[i] == NULL)
        {
            puts("failed to allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if (ptrWords == NULL)
    {
        puts("failed to allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < strSize; i++)
    {
        if (ptrChFromFile[i] != ' ')
        {
            ptrWords[j][k++] = ptrChFromFile[i];
        }
        else
        {
            ptrWords[j][k] = 0;
            ptrWords[j] = realloc(ptrWords[j], k+1);
            j++;
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", ptrWords[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < strSize; i++) {
        free(ptrWords[i]);
    }
    free(ptrChFromFile);
    free(ptrWords);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I have edited the code in the question to reflect the suggestions you provided, but now the program crashes, and the when trying to print the first element it prints the the whole string "hey there" should only print "hey" not "hey there" Thank you

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Readers need to see the original code that I was answering, or the answer doesn't make sense. If you want to show how you tried to implement this, add it at the end, don't replace the original.

Comment: apologies I have added on my implementation to the end. if I delete the for loop that allocates memory for each [i] then the program crashes. I agree with you that I am allocating to much memory, but I am unsure of how to fix it. Also, I don't understand why I am not getting the desired output. Thank you

Comment: I found a few more problems and updated the answer with explanations and the full working code.

Comment: Thank you for the help ptrWords is working correctly. I just need help with the last part of this program. I have added the current version of the code that I have and the I have explained the last few issues I am facing any help would be great thank you.

Comment: You ignored all the corrections I made in my last update to the answer yesterday. Compare your version with mine and you'll see the problems.

Comment: The most important one is that it should start with `int strSize = 0;`, not `int strSize = 1;`.

Comment: I have fixed my code to match yours, but now I am having trouble comparing the word and making sure it is greater than or equal to 6  before adding to my ptrCrunchWord, and also coming up with a statement that checks to if a word already exist in ptrCrunchWord

Comment: The starting value of 1 was my fault in the linked question (fixed now). It accounts for the space for terminating 0. If you start with 0 instead you need to adjust memory allocation accordingly.

Comment: You're right, I missed that detail. Either use `realloc(strSize + 2)`, or do another `realloc` before adding the null at the end. I don't know what `ptrCrunchWord` is, there's nothing about that in the question.

Comment: @Barmar I have added the current version of the code to the original  question post along with an explanation of the last couple of issues

Comment: Why should the OP copy the words? The allocation of new memory is not required if the OP just stores a pointer. Of course they need to be terminated with a `\0` in the initial buffer. No extra `malloc`, `realloc`, `free` and copying for each word needed.

Comment: @Gerhardh In a real program it would depend on what you're doing with the strings later. This is clearly just an exercise on using pointers and copying data.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to show a version more like your initial version.

I will skip the part reading the file. The fix related to `strSize` mentioned by Barmar needs to be applied of course.
This code starts after reading your file.

```
    ptrChFromFile[strSize] = 0;

    ptrWords = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numberOfWords); //creates number of slots in ptr

    if (ptrWords == NULL)
    {
        puts("failed to allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    #define MIN_LENGTH 6
    int start = 0, end = 0;
    numWords = 0; // Start counting again. Only handle words long enough.
    for (i = 0; i < strSize; i++) // Walk the inital array again
    {
        if (ptrChFromFile[i] == ` `)
        {
          end = i;
          if (end - start >= MIN_LENGTH)
          { // Found a word? Store address and terminate.
            ptrWords = &ptrChFromFile[start];
            ptrChFromFile[i] = 0;
            numWords ++;
          }
          // Words that are too short are ignored
          // Also if a second space follows, no new word is counted...

          // Prepare for new word starting at next position.
          start = end = i+1;
        }
    }

    // Maybe one more word without a space afterwards?
    end = i;
    if (end - start >= MIN_LENGTH)
    { // Found a word? Store address and terminate.
      ptrWords = &ptrChFromFile[start];
      // ptrChFromFile[i] = 0; This word is already terminated.
      numWords ++;
    }

    ptrWords = realloc(sizeof(char*) * numberOfWords); // Reduce size to only hold long words

    // Decide number n how many words shall be concatenated
    // Use scanf or any other mechanism...
    int n = numWords / 2;
```

For selecting the words I will use an array to hold only the index of each word.
It is initialized with index 0..n-1.
For each selected word I move the index to first location in the array and put the (former) first element to the selected position.
After this the first n elements hold random index values.
As the range for random selection is decreased in each step no duplcates are possible.
Not comparing of words is required.

```
    // Create an array to hold the indices of chosen words.
    int selectedWords[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      selectedWords[i] = i;

    // Select n words, store index.
    srand(time(0));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {     
      // Pick random element 0..n
      int elem = rand()%(n-i);
      int temp;
      temp = selectedWords[i+elem];
      selectedWords[i+elem] = selectedWords[i];
      selectedWords[i] = temp;
    }
    // This first n entries hold the selected words.

    // How long will it be in the end?
    size_t len = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      len += strlen(ptrWords[selectedWords[n]]);     
    }

    // Get memory for final result...
    char *resultWord = malloc(len+1);
    // TODO: check for NULL
    resultWord[0] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      strcat(resultWord, ptrWords[selectedWords[n]]);     
    }
    printf("%s\n", resultWord)

    free(ptrChFromFile);
    free(ptrWords);
    free(resultWord);

    return 0;
}
```

The code is not compiled or tested.