# remove leading spaces from string in c

Tags: c

I am reading in a string character by character then for each word found(separated by space) counting the length of each word, and finally printing all that information to the screen.

`Sample run:      trickier to  master`

```
    n=8, s=[trickier]
    n=2, s=[to]
    n=6, s=[master]
    n=0, s=[]
    n=-1, s=[]
```

This is correct what I get is this:

```
    n=0, s=[]
    n=0, s=[]
    n=8, s=[trickier]
    n=2, s=[to]
    n=0, s=[]
    n=6, s=[master]
    n=0, s=[]
    n=-1, s=[]
```

The problem is the leading spaces in the string I have looked at a lot of examples of how to trim the leading spaces, but I couldn't get anything to work with my current source code.

Code:

```
#include "getword.h"

int getword(char *w) {
    int iochar;
    int index = 0;
    int numberofchars = 0;

    if (numberofchars == 0 && iochar == '\n') {
        w[index] = '\0';
        iochar = EOF;
        return 0;
    }
    if (iochar == EOF && numberofchars == 0) {
        w[index] = '\0';
        return -1;
    }

    while ((iochar = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (iochar != ' ' && iochar != '\n') {
            w[index] = iochar;
            index++;
            numberofchars++;
        } else {
            w[index] = '\0';
            if (strcmp(w, "done") == 0) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return numberofchars;
            }
        }
    } //after while loop
} // end of function

int main() {
    int c;
    char s[STORAGE];

    for (;;) {
        (void)printf("n=%d, s=[%s]\n", c = getword(s), s);
        if (c == -1)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a blank space to represent a space, use unicode or utf-8 hex codes. Also check your system encoding.

Comment: @BitShift — would you care to elaborate on what you're thinking?

Comment: You test `iochar` before it is initialized or assigned a value; this is not going to lead to happiness.  Erratic indentation is also going to lead to a different sort of unhappiness; it makes it hard to read your code accurately.

Comment: OT: `(void) printf(...`: `(void)` is totally pointless here, just write `printf(...`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, certainly! Unicode: U+0020. HEX: 0x20.

Comment: @BitShift — if comments could be down-voted, I'd down-vote yours.  The character `' '` is a better choice for all practical purposes; it would even work with EBCDIC whereas your options would not.  If you want to allow for variant space representations (non-breaking spaces, narrow spaces, ZWNJ (zero-width non-joiner) and the like), you should probably use `isspace()` or `isblank()` from `<ctype.h>`, probably in conjunction with `setlocale()` from `<localed.h>`.

Comment: Did you learn anything from the answer to [… How to parse words by space in C? …](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035450/need-to-know-how-to-parse-words-by-space-in-c-also-need-to-know-if-i-am-allocat) which you asked in March 2019?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't think that it's pointless. It makes clear that the code ignores any problem that `printf()` might have had. Coming from a safety background where it's not allowed to ignore returned values, I got used to this style, too.

Comment: @thebusybee maybe in certain contexts it's not pointless, but at the level of this question it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is way too complicated, with some useless and bogus tests producing undefined behavior:

- testing `iochar` in `getword()` before you even read it with `getchar()` makes no sense.
- combining reading, testing and writing the words in a single `printf()` call is bogus too: you should instead read, then test, then output if not done.

Here is a simplified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STORAGE 50

// read a word into an array of size `size`.
// return the number of characters read.
int getword(char *w, size_t size) {
    int c;
    size_t i = 0;

    while (i + 1 < size && (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n') {
            if (i == 0)
                continue;  // ignore leading spaces
            else
                break;     // stop on white space following the word.
        }
        w[i++] = c;
    }
    w[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int main() {
    char s[STORAGE];
    int len;

    while ((len = getword(s, sizeof s)) != 0) {
        if (!strcmp(s, "done"))
            break;
        printf("n=%d, s=[%s]\n", len, s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make the code produce desired output, but this is all I could do. There were some bugs which I thought and so I fixed them. See the comments in the code for more details. Hope that solves the problem.

```
int getword(char * w) {
    int iochar = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int numberofchars = 0;

    // I really don't know why those if conditions were required
    // Thought they were useless so removed them

    while ((iochar = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (iochar != ' ' && iochar != '\n') {
            w[index++] = iochar;   // slight change here
            numberofchars++;
        } else {
            w[index] = '\0';
            // I don't know what this condition is supposed to mean
            // so I ignored it
            if (strcmp(w, "done") == 0) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return numberofchars;
            }
        }
    } //after while loop

    // Since EOF is encountered, no more characters to read
    // So terminate the string with '\0'
    w[index] = '\0';

    // Here after the loop you should check if some characters were read, but not
    // handled. If there are any, return them because that's what you last read
    // before EOF was encountered
    return (numberofchars > 0 ? numberofchars : -1);
} // end of function



int main()
{
    int c;
    char s[STORAGE];

    for (;;) {
        // Put the if condition before printing because if -1 is returned
        // it doesn't make sense to print the string at all
        c = getword(s);
        if (c == -1) break;
        printf("n=%d, s=[%s]\n", c, s);
    }
}
```

Here's where I tested this: http://ideone.com/bmfaA3

Comment: "// Always memset …": It is not necessary to initialize memory/variable if it is not read before the next write. This pattern (double write before read) is an anti-pattern showing that you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: @thebusybee, you are right. I just wanted to be safe. I have had bad experience with buffer overflow, so I memset the buffer whenever I have to (freshly) write anything into it. Given that, I have changed that comment a bit.

Comment: I understand your point. But setting some buffer to a known value doesn't save you from buffer overflows. If the code does not crash the "cure" just hides the real error. That's what we call "program at random": "Oh, it crashes!" - "What if I try this?…" - "Oh, now it doesn't crash. Great, this must be good." :-D